# Is there any encryption-decryption library working same in jquery as well as in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking for an encryption-decryption library which is working same on both rails and jquery. I mean I will encrypt some data in rails and then send it in response to ajax call and I want to decrypt it in jquery.

So, Is there any common library?

Comment: If you want to encrypt and decrypt between client and server then what your looking for is probably `https`

Comment: The third party will request on my server for some data to display on their page. In short, they are calling my API and use respond data on their page.

Comment: If you encrypt the data with ruby and decrypt with JS anyone can read the JS and decrypt the data for themselves. You are making it slightly more difficult to decrypt but not by much.

Comment: @HMR Exactly that is what I want. So, normal people cannot easily read my data.

Comment: If users need authentication for your API's then anyone can read that if you're using `http` if it's not authenticated then you or 3rd party need to provide decryption keys that can also be plainly read when using `http`. This is not really secure but you can have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a common library, just a common standard. I have no trouble transferring encrypted messages between browser Javascript and Node.js or PHP based servers, on three very different libraries.

Any browser encryption for any reason should be done with the [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) built-in library, because it uses better entropy generation and is less susceptible to timing-based attacks than third-party libraries can be. You'll want either AES-CBC for private-key encryption or RSA-OAEP for public-key encryption.

This is not a subject I'm going to delve into too deeply in a post, but be prepared for a lot of homework and testing to get everything coordinated. You'll also want a good grasp of character encodings, and you might end up with multiple manual character conversions. I have my doubts as to your intentions (I think you're completely wasting your time, for reasons already mentioned) but I prefer to give answers rather than advice. Have fun!